# How do I customize the size (width) of the SideMenuBar (hamburger menu) in Codename One

Tags: java, user-interface, codenameone

I have a sidemenu bar in Codename One implemented using [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/hamburger-sidemenu.html), I'm considering the switch to the newer [Toolbar API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toolbar.html) but both seems to be one and the same.

I'd like to customize the width to which the side menu bar opens, this is somewhat opaque within the UI and there are no setters I can see since the API consists of `addCommand(new Command("My Command");`

[This blog post](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/on-the-side-up-on-top.html) mentioned a lot of options but didn't mention the width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual covers [some theme constants](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html#_theme_constants) that allow you to customize the side menu. Specifically:

- `sideMenuSizeTabPortraitInt` The size of the side menu when expanded in a tablet in portrait mode
- `sideMenuSizePortraitInt` The size of the side menu when expanded in a phone in portrait mode
- `sideMenuSizeTabLandscapeInt` The size of the side menu when expanded in a tablet in landscape mode
- `sideMenuSizeLandscapeInt` The size of the side menu when expanded in a phone in landscape mode

You can set these by opening the designer tool, selecting the theme and selecting the "Constants" tab where you can just add anyt one of those.

All of these sizes are in screen percentages.

Comment: how can I change the size of a command within the Menu? (The height of a command)